# "Open containing folder" from Activities search

Tags: gnome-shell, search, activities-overview

Using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

If I use the Super key to search for a file, the path of the containing folder is displayed on screen, but there seems to be no way to either open the containing folder directly, or to copy the path.

Am I missing something, or is this not a supported feature?

Comment: It used to be the case with Unity but unfortunately this is no longer available with Gnome. If anyone knows whether this feature has been requested to the developers, please let me know also where I can support the request. Sorry Bogen...

Comment: Anyone testing 20.04: Is such a feature not available in 20.04 also?